# Having Trouble in Retrieve Data from CSV and save it into a List

Tags: python, list

My Data.csv file look like this:

```
0001 ABC 
0002 CDE 
0003 FGH
```

I intended to put into a list namely tickerinfo:

> tickerinfo = [['00001','ABC'],['00002','CDE'],['00003','FGH']]

My Code:

```
import csv

tickerinfo = [] 
ticker=['','']


with open('Data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')        
    for row in readCSV:
        ticker[0] = row[0]
        ticker[0] = '0000' + str(ticker[0])
        ticker[0] = ticker[0][-5:]
        ticker[1] = row[1]
        tickerinfo.append(ticker)
    print(tickerinfo)
```

The Result:

> [['00003', 'FGH'], ['00003', 'FGH'], ['00003', 'FGH']]

Why would that happen? And how to solve the problem? Why all the elements are 0003 instead of 0001,0002 and 0003 in order?

Comment: `print(readCSV)` exhausts the iterator object. Remove that line.

Comment: Also, you probably want to be using `zfill` rather concatenating the zeros on yourself

Comment: The edit to remove that line isn't helpful if that was actually in your real code because you've now removed the problem you describe.

Comment: I still have unwanted result, do you know why the result of the three elements are te same, all of hem are 0003

Comment: Look at the answers below and see if any of them explain the cause of your issue and provide an appropriate fix.

Comment: You need `ticker=['','']` inside the for loop. You have a single object being appended multiple times. You need to redefine it on each iteration.

Comment: thanks a lot, didnt notice i made such stupid mistake..thanks roganjosh!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

with open('Data.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ')
    tickerinfo= [[row[0].zfill(5), row[1]] for row in readCSV]
```

Your code is working fine the only little problem is that you append `ticker` three times to your result, in the first, itreation ticker will be `['0001', 'ABC']`but when you chnage `ticker` you will change the `ticker` that already added to your result, for your beter understanding add `print(tickerinfo)` inside the loop, you will get :

```
[['00001', 'ABC']]
[['00002 ', 'CDE'], ['00002 ', 'CDE']]
[['00003', 'FGH'], ['00003', 'FGH'], ['00003', 'FGH']]
```

so for fixing your code, you can use `copy` or `[:]` like this:

```
 tickerinfo.append(ticker[:])
```

or

```
from copy import copy

tickerinfo.append(ticker.copy())
```

Comment: Why `split`? And now you've lost the second value of each row. Plus it doesn't zfill

Comment: thanks! seems working but why my original code doesnt work at all and all my elements are the same (data from the third row in Data.csv)

Answer (score 0):

you are using `delimiter=','` but the csv file is separated by `' '` (space), so change delimiter to `delimiter=' '`. 
You can do like this:

```
import csv

ticker_info = []
with open('Data.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for i in reader:
        # use zfill if you want more zeros
        ticker_info.append( [i[0].zfill(5), i[1]] ) 

print(ticker_info) // result [['00001', 'ABC'], ['00002', 'CDE'], ['00003', 'FGH']]
```